# Determining the last changelist synced to in Perforce

Tags: perforce

A question that occasionally arises is what is the best way to determine the changelist that you last synced to in Perforce. This is often needed for things like injecting the changelist number into the revision info by the automatic build system.

Comment: `p4 changes | head -1` seems easier than most of these solutions.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I recommend the opposite for automatic build systems: you should first get the latest changelist from the server using:

```
p4 changes -s submitted -m1
```

then sync to that change and record it in the revision info.  The reason is as follows.  Although [Perforce recommends the following](https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/3458) to determine the changelist to which the workspace is synced:

```
p4 changes -m1 @clientname
```

they note a few gotchas:

- This only works if you have not submitted anything from the workspace in question.
- It is also possible that a client workspace is not synced to any specific changelist.

and there's an additional gotcha they don't mention:

- If the highest changelist to which the sync occured strictly deleted files from the workspace, the next-highest changelist will be reported (unless it, too, strictly deleted files).

If you must sync first and record later, Perforce recommends running the following command to determine if you've been bit by the above gotchas; it should indicate nothing was synced or removed:

```
p4 sync -n @changelist_number
```

Note that this method doesn't work if a file is added in a changelist (n-1) and then deleted in the very next changelist (n). `p4 changes -m1 @clientname` and `p4 changes ...#have` both return n-3 and `p4 sync -n @n-3` will say "file(s) up-to-date."

Comment: Why is it that "This only works if you have not submitted anything from the workspace in question."?

Comment: If you submit a change, 'p4 changes -s submitted -m1' will return your changelist number. For example, say you sync to changelist 5, wait a couple hours and then submit changelist 10. The above changes command will return 10.

Comment: The link is dead, was it this article? answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3458/

Comment: Note that you can use `#have` instead of `@clientname`, which saves you from having to look up your client workspace name.

Answer (score 32):

Just to answer this myself in keeping with Jeff's suggestion of using Stackoverflow as a place to keep technical snippets....

From the command line use:

```
p4 changes -m1 @<clientname>
```

And just replace  with the name of your client spec. This will produce output of the form:

```
Change 12345 on 2008/08/21 by joebloggs@mainline-client '....top line of description...'
```

Which is easily parsed to extract the changelist number.

Comment: I am getting: Request too large (over 1500000); see 'p4 help maxresults'.

Comment: @user674669: use option -m1 which returns only last (1) change list

Comment: This gives the information of the last _submitted_ changelist, not the last _synced_ changelist, which is what the op wanted to know.

Comment: @marsh I think it's actually the client workspace name, which defaults to the computer name if not set. See here: [P4CLIENT](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/P4CLIENT.html).

Answer (score 16):

You may try finding the maximum change number in the output of the "p4 files" command.  The working directory should not contain post-sync commits, though.  This is just a tad better than

```
p4 changes -m1 "./...#have"
```

as the latter seems to run on the server and may fail on big source trees due to "MaxResults" limits.

```
$ p4 changes -m1 "./...#have"
Request too large (over 850000); see 'p4 help maxresults'.

$ p4 -G files "./...#have" | python c:/cygwin/usr/local/bin/p4lastchange.py
Files: 266948
2427657
```

where p4lastchange.py is based on the code from the [Using P4G.py From the Command Line](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/conferences/us/2005/presentations/GoldstonePresentation.pdf) presentation by J.T.Goldstone, Kodak Information Network/Ofoto, April 15, 2005.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, marshal

if os.name == "nt":
    # Disable newline translation in Windows.  Other operating systems do not
    # translate file contents.
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode( sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY )

lastcl = 0
num = 0
try:
    while 1:
        dict = marshal.load(sys.stdin)
        num = num + 1
        for key in dict.keys():
            # print "%s: %s" % (key,dict[key])
            if key == "change":
                cl = int(dict[key])
                if cl > lastcl:
                    lastcl = cl
except EOFError:
    pass
print "Files: %s" % num
print lastcl
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using P4V you can do this graphically:

- In the Dashboard tab (View->Dashboard) choose a folder and you will see a list of changelists that the folder isn't yet updated with. Note the lowest number (in the highest row).
- Make sure that in the Workspace Tree you have selected the same folder as previously in the Dashboard. Then go to the History tab (View->History) and scroll down to the number noted previously. The number just below that number is the number of your current changelist.

Comment: The Dashboard view doesn't work when the folder contains a lot of files (100,000) and more.

Answer (score 11):

`p4 changes -m1 @clientname` which is the "recommended" way to do it for my client takes about 10 minutes

this is what I use:

```
p4 cstat ...#have | grep change | awk '$3 > x { x = $3 };END { print x }'
```

for the same client takes 2.1 seconds

Comment: What is client name? How can I find this information?

Comment: @marsh client (or also workspace) name is the name of a perforce object that holds the mapping from the server depo to your local file system

Comment: Upvoting this answer, since it answers the actual question rather than saying “don’t do that” (which is a valid point, but does not answer the question).

Comment: `p4 changes -m1 @clientname` run endlessly... `p4 cstat ...#have | grep change | awk '$3 > x { x = $3 };END { print x }'` really works! Thanks!

Comment: @gsf - thanks, just tried it on my Linux box and it worked!

Answer (score 9):

You could also use the cstat command:

p4 help cstat

```
cstat -- Dump change/sync status for current client

p4 cstat [files...]

Lists changes that are needed, had or partially synced in the current
client. The output is returned in tagged format, similar to the fstat
command.

The fields that cstat displays are:

    change   changelist number
    status   'have', 'need' or 'partial'
```

Comment: This worked best for me, I did the command  p4 cstat > commits.txt
then I opened the generated text file in notepad++ and did a ctrl+F to the first instance of the word "need"

Answer (score 5):

For a serious build (one that is being prepared for testing), explicitly specify the desired label or changelist number, *sync to label,* and imbed it in build artifacts.

If a changelist (or label) is not given, use `p4 counter change` to get the current change number, and record it. But you still need to *sync everything using that change number.*

I don't think you can achieve exactly what you want, because in general, an entire workspace isn't synced to a particular changelist number. One can explicitly sync some files to older revisions, and then a single changelist number is meaningless. That's why a fresh `sync` is required to ensure that a single changelist number accurately represents the code version.

---

Regarding the comments: Yes, my answer is intended for use by configuration managers preparing a build to give to QA. Our developers don't normally sync as part of a build; they do a build prior to submitting—so that they can make sure their changes don't break the build or tests. In that context, we don't bother to embed a repository label.

With your approach, you are making the assumption that your whole workspace was synced to head at the time of your last changelist submission, and that changelist included all of your open files. It's too easy to be mistaken in those assumptions, hard to detect, and horribly expensive in terms of lost time. On the other hand, solving the problem is easy, with no drawbacks. And because a changelist number can be explicitly specified, it doesn't matter what revision you need or how quickly the codebase is changing.

Comment: Erickson - nice suggestion, but I think it covers a slightly different set of circumstances than the answer I provided. Certainly counter will work if you are likely to only have the head revision, and the server is not busy enough so that someone, perhaps working on another project, would not do a submit between syncing and calling p4 counter. So I think your suggestion is probably best when the build system is doing a distinct pull then build. My answer covers cases where the sync may be separated in time from the build. Both are valid depending on circumstances I think.

Answer (score 3):

For the whole depot (not just your workspace/client)

```
p4 counter change
```

does the job, just telling the last changelist.

Comment: Note that this reports the number of the latest depot changelist, INCLUDING pending (ie not-yet-submitted) changelists. So any user starting some new work in their client will affect this number. This will be different from the last changelist synced to the local workspace.

Answer (score 2):

The best I've found so far is to do your sync to whatever changelist you want to build and then use changes -m1 //...#have to get the current local changelist (revision).

p4 sync @CHANGELIST_NUM
p4 changes -m1 //...#have | awk '{print $2}'

Gives you the changelist number that you can the use wherever you want.  I am currently looking for a simpler way than p4 changes -m1 //...#have.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you got the answer you needed but I had a similar problem. The goal was to write in our logger the specific version of the project. The problem was that while we are making our own makefile, the overall build system is controlled by our configuration management. This means that all the solutions which say "sync to something then do something" don't really work and I didn't want to manually change the version whenever we commit (a sure source for errors). 
The solution (which is actually hinted in some of the answers above) is this:
in our makefile, I do p4 changes -m1 "./...#have"
The result for this is Change change_number on date by user@client 'msg'
I simply create the message into a string which is printed by the logger (the change number is the important element but the other is also useful to quickly decide if a certain version contains changes you know you made yourself without going to perforce to check).
Hope this helps.