# How can I find out the change set number of my current P4 workspace

Tags: perforce

I have not synced for about 3 weeks.
How can I find out the change set number of my local copy of  P4 workspace (which is not the latest revision)?

I tried 'p4 counter change', that seems to give me the latest revision in my P4 workspace remotely. I check the time in the 'history tab' of my P4 client'. The number I get from 'p4 counter change' is more recent than the last time I did a sync in P4.

I have tried 'p4 changes -m1 //path/to/your/project/...#have', but I get 
'//path/to/your/project/... - must create client 'LTMN-MIKE' to access local files'
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining the last changelist synced to in Perforce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007/determining-the-last-changelist-synced-to-in-perforce)

Comment: Try `p4 changes -m1 ...#have` from within your client's local root.